# Could not detect default username. Please provide one explicitly

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose

Getting this error when conneccting golang container to postgres.

> pq: Could not detect default username. Please provide one explicitly

I have tried many usernames and password combinations with no luck.  What username combination should I be using?

docker-compose code is:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.1-alpine
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    #network_mode: bridge
    container_name: postgres

    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'user'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'password'
      POSTGRESS_DB: 'db_amex01'
    volumes:
      - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/


  todo:
    build: ./go_amex/
    depends_on:
      - "postgres"
    restart: always

    # ports:
    #   - "8000:8080"
```

./go_amex/main.go

```
db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "host='postgres'&user=user@localhost&port=5432&dbname='todo'&password='password'&sslmode=disable")

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("============   exiting ==========")
    fmt.Println(err)
    panic("failed to connect database cc")
}

defer db.Close()
```

[Github code for the challenge](https://github.com/vinceyoumans/v05)

Comment: What's in the `./init` directory?

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid postgres connection string. Gorm uses lib/pq to connect to postgres so take a look at its documentation to see how the connection string should be formatted (https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq). Its either space separated key-value pairs or a url, ie no ampersands.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: kartoza/postgis:9.6-2.4
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: developer
      POSTGRES_DBNAME: somedb
      POSTGRES_PASS: somepass
    volumes:
      - $HOME/data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

config for database in yaml

```
sqlBind := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
    "developer",
    "somepass",
    "somedb",
)
```

Comment: First try to change postgres image